# How to bind a DataGridComboBoxColumn of a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

My project uses MVVM and I want to bind a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to the viewmodel.

The combobox shall have the items "<" (with key "1") and "<=" (with key "2").

First i have an `observablecollection` with the comboboxitems:

```
public ObservableCollection<ArithmeticSignData> LowerComparerItems { get; set; }
```

This is the class ArithmeticSignData:

```
public class ArithmeticSignData
{
    public ArithmeticSignData(string key, string value)
    {
        ArithmeticSignKey = key;
        ArithmeticSignValue = value;
    }

    public string ArithmeticSignKey { get; set; }
    public string ArithmeticSignValue { get; set; }
}
```

When my viewmodel is initialized i fill the list LowerComparerItems:

```
private void FillLowerComparerItemsList()
{
    LowerComparerItems = new ObservableCollection<ArithmeticSignData>();
    LowerComparerItems.Add(new ArithmeticSignData("1", "<"));
    LowerComparerItems.Add(new ArithmeticSignData("2", "<="));
}
```

The data for the datagrid comes from another observablecollection with an entity framework table as type.
That table has a column called "low_operator".
So i thought it would be possible to bind the comboboxcolumn by the following.
When i open the combobox i can see the items.
But after starting the app the values from the table are not translated to "<" or "<=".

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbc_LowerComparer"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding low_operator, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ArithmeticSignValue"
                                    Header=" "
                                    Width="30">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.LowerComparerItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.LowerComparerItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should the `Selected`**Value**`Binding` property to your binding and also set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "ArithmeticSignKey":

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbc_LowerComparer"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding low_operator, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    SelectedValuePath="ArithmeticSignKey"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ArithmeticSignValue"
                                    Header=" "
                                    Width="30">
```

This should set the `low_operator` column to the value of the selected `ArithmeticSignKey` value. If you want to set it to the `ArithmeticSignValue` you should set the `SelectedValuePath` property of the column to the name of this one instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot mm8! ComboBoxes are difficult enough, but inside the DataGrid they are much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Your code like this :

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="cbc_LowerComparer"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding LowerComparerItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding low_operator, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="ArithmeticSignValue"
                                Header=" "
                                Width="30">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SelectedItemBinding use this...

```
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding low_operator}"
```